# What are the security implications of disabling requiretty in sudoers?

Tags: linux, centos, sudo

If we add the following lines to sudoers:

```
Defaults    requiretty
Defaults:apache !requiretty
apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /etc/init.d/httpd graceful
```

What are the security implications?
My understanding is that: "web users" can gracefully restart the httpd server if they can manage an injection?

Any other dangers?

Answer (score 4):

`requiretty` indicates that `sudo` may used even if there is no interactive shell/session.

The security impact depends on the system settings. If the apache user could write to `/etc/init.d/httpd` or change the behaviour of the init-script by changing some parameters in `/etc/defaults` an attacker could do just everything.

You should **not** give your web-server any higher privileges on the system as long as it is really needed.

Comment: What do we mean by "writing to /etc/init.d/httpd" ?

Comment: Writing like modifing the file @Haluk

Comment: I still don't follow. Isn't httpd a compiled binary file. How can you write to it? I've googled "writing to httpd" and some other versions, no luck with that either. And more importantly, what "system setting" would grant me the access to write to httpd?

Comment: But the `/etc/init.d/httpd` is a script. You should learn the linux basic, before doing thinks like  giving sudo to the www user!

Comment: Thank you I didn't know this. I read the script now. From what I understand if someone could modify the httpd script they can pretty much mess up all web folders without any additional privileges? And since we are only giving privilege to the "graceful" option. The attacker would also need to be able to read our sudoers file to find out our vulnerability? Or is the danger coming from `Defaults:apache !requiretty`?

Comment: If somepne could modify the script, he could get root privileges on the system. Just don't do it, there is realy no reason to give the webserver this privileges.